# Is it possible to import another module in singleton class module in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one module as singleton class. In that singleton class module, I want to import other module, which is not singleton. Is it possible to import ?

While I am importing module and run to singleton module then I got error that singleton module is not defined.

for e.g:
first_file.py:

```
class first(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "first class"
```

second_file.py

```
from Libs.first_file import * #here libs is my folder /module
@singleton
class second(self):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Second class"
```

when I ran:
 python second_file.py

I got error NameError: name 'second_file()' is not defined
but when commented out import, then second_file() module is working as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should provide more detail.For example,the detail of your `@singleton`

I had a test on the code you provided.I added the decorator myself,and change `class second(self):` to `class second(first):`,as following:

first_file.py:

```
class first(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "first class"
```

second_file.py:

```
from first_file import *  # here libs is my folder /module


def singleton(class_):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance(*args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in instances:
            instances[class_] = class_(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[class_]
    return getinstance


@singleton
class second(first):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Second class"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = second()
    test1 = second()
```

When I ran python second_file.py:

```
Second class
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

It seems to be ok.
Maybe I don't get the point of your problem,but hope it helps.